blazor client project css stylesheet file not found
Folks, i have looked but not able to find an answer to what i imagine should be pretty straightfotward.
i have instantiated a default Blazor template with two projects (as per default template). sorry for using screenshot but its easier to cover the picture of what is going on rather than long text.
i am aiming at maintaining some stylesheets in the Client project. i have created a sample client-styles.css file in the Client project and i expect to be able to consume it on the main App.razor also as per screenshot.

Everything else is pretty much left as default. However, my problem is - the application is not finding it when ran.

i am obviously missing something obvious. can someone please point me in the right direction. thank you.

Apparently, Blazor Web App is smart enough to build the client porject side CSS files into its primary CSS source so there is no need to reference a client project library in the css files source when including a stylesheet, but rather include it as direct stylesheeet like so:
<link href="/css/client-project-styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />

